# Twitter API rate limits for posting updates

Tags: twitter, status, updates, limits, rate

I have an application for sending out say around 100+ tweets every day. I am using OAuth for authentication. The twitter API says that post messages are not rate limited. However I am receiving the following error:

403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits (http://support.twitter.com/forums/10711/entries/15364).
error - **User is over daily status update limit.**
request - /1/statuses/update.json
Relevant discussions can be on the Internet at:
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=15bb6564 or
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=010f3e5b
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[15bb6564-010f3e5b], statusCode=403, retryAfter=0, rateLimitStatus=null, version=2.1.11}

Does this mean that status update API calls are also rate limited?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Yes Status updates are rate limited. but 100 per day won't be an issue.

Current Twitter Limits

**The current technical limits for accounts are:**

1. Updates: 1,000 per day. The daily update limit is further broken down into smaller limits for semi-hourly intervals. Retweets are counted as updates.

From : http://support.twitter.com/forums/10711/entries/15364

Comment: If they have semi hourly limits that means that means I can send only 20 updates in 1/2 hour. But I was able to send like 100 updates in 15 min span and I get an exception only after that. If I send the next tweet after waiting for 2 hrs, it again fails.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some kind of shared hosting? the twitter API is limited by IP address and if there are other apps on your IP address also using the twitter API then you will be sharing rate limits with them. I ran into this issue with a tiny app on google app engine, despite only making about 10 requests in an hour.

Comment: No. I am not using any shared hosting. I am authenticated using OAuth. So if am right, it does user rate limiting and not IP address rate limiting.

Answer (score 0):

The update limit is 1000 per day.But these are divided into intervals in which different amount of tweets are allowed per window. You can follow [this](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/3879) thread.

```
Does this mean that status update API calls are also rate limited?
```

Yes,but not directly. As "The twitter API says that post messages are not rate limited" is true but not all POST requests are status update calls.